# How to install a specific version of GLIBCXX?

Tags: c++, g++

I need to install up to GLIBCXX_3.4.2, but not later. All the instructions I have found let you install the latest version right away. I am a beginner so please be a little detailed.

Comment: That depends on your OS. At least on Linux it's best to use your package manager for this.

Comment: "I need to install up to GLIBCXX_3.4.2, but not later." -- no, you don't. Please describe your *actual* problem.

Comment: My problem is that I need to run some code on a cluster that only has up to GLIBCXX_3.4.2 and not later. So I need to have that on my machine as well.

Answer (score 0):

`GLIBCXX_3.4.2` is *extremely* old; it's from 2004 or so.  It's unlikely that this version is your actual baseline requirement.

You need to figure out what operating system version the cluster uses, set up a chroot or virtual machine with that, and use that to build your software.